# plotting multiple y values for a single x in plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dictionary of values something like this:

```
MTUS = {'0':MTU_1,'1':MTU_2, '2':MTU_3}
```

where MTU_X is a series of 96 different values, and the really dictionary contains 24 elements.

I want to plot the keys for x and the values in the series for y, so for each x I get 96 points.

something like this

```
x = list(MTUS.keys())
y = list(MTUS.values())

fig = px.scatter(x=range(len(MTUS)), y=y, title="Forecast distribution for 01/01/2023")
```

but then i get the error

```
ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `wide_variable_0` is 96, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['x'] is 2
```

how do I iterate through the rows to plot everything from one MTUX series onto a single x value?

Is it also possible to change the colors so each y value for one x has a gradient of color that persists across all x values?

Comment: Every point needs an X-Y pair. You are now trying to cast a list of Y-values to a single X.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, as stated in the post title.

Comment: My bad. PX is smarter than I thought. I tried to reproduce with a minimal example, but I don't get any error. However, it does not produce the graph I think you want. The method works in principle, so there is something wrong with that data that causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code I replaced your dictionary keys by true letters instead of integers as strings, because that it a bit confusing.
Using go instead of px, because that gives a bit more low-level control.

The color is now one scale. If you leave out the cmin and cmax specification in the plot, the colorscale will be applied per trace (i.e. per key).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

MTU_1 = [1,2,3]
MTU_2 = [4,5,6]
MTU_3 = [7,8,9]

MTUS = {'A':MTU_1,'B':MTU_2, 'C':MTU_3}

df = pd.DataFrame(MTUS)  # convert to DataFrame

cmin = min(np.hstack(df.values))  # get minimum value of the whole set
cmax = max(np.hstack(df.values))  # get maximum value of the whole set

fig = go.Figure()

for c in df.columns:
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=[c]*len(df[c]),  # construct list of identical X values to match the Y-list
            y=df[c],  # Your MTU list
            mode='markers',  # scatter plot without lines
            marker=dict(
                color=df[c],  # set color by the value of Y
                cmin=cmin,  # absolute color scaling min value
                cmax=cmax,  # absolute color scaling max value
                ),
                name=c,
            )
            )

fig.update_layout(height=500, width=500)
fig.show()
```

[image: Output plot]